# How to set the Evil Bit on outgoing traffic

Tags: linux, security, networking, ip

So for a security related application I'm writing, I actually want to use RFC3514 ("The Evil Bit") to determine what set of traffic across the network is evil or not at a per packet level. This is used as training data for an assisted machine learning engine, so the app has to know before hand what packets are evil and which are not.

This ought to be fairly simple, it's just setting a single IP layer bit. I've tried looking into doing this with iptables or libpcap, but either they don't have the functionality or I failed to discover it.

Being able to set it for all traffic out of a machine would be fine, but filters on what comes out would be better. (Like being able to specify what higher layer protocols get it set, etc...)

I'm using Ubuntu, as well. So Linux solutions preferred. But otherwise, it doesn't really matter what method is used to accomplish this. Bash script, c/c++ app, setting some sysctl, whatever.

Comment: +1 Interesting,  but I think the defacto standard of dropping or logging these packets by an IPS/IDS is a more secure approach.

Comment: Well, the whole point is that I don't want to use a signature based IPS/IDS. Hence the machine learning portion. But that's not really relevant to the question, just some background info. I could have equivalently asked "How can I set a flag in outgoing packets without otherwise disturbing their operation / interpretation?" It seems unlikely that I'm the first person to ever have that need.

Comment: Ten months later one wonders whether you are successfully filtering out all the evil network traffic.  You don't happen to work for Sony, do you?

Comment: lol, I think most people here are misunderstanding my question. I am well aware that RFC3514 is an April Fools RFC. I am not intending to use it as a method of determining if traffic is actually hostile or not.

I want to have a flag on a per-packet level to tell an application I'm making "this packet is hostile". For the purposes of training a machine learning algorithm. It's like having a "this is spam" flag in an email in order to train a spam filter.

In any case, it turned out to not be possible in Linux without kernel mods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently this was actually implemented for FreeBSD - maybe you could look at their code?

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/3514.html

Comment: I see that, but:
1) A kernel patch seems like overkill
2) The actual link to the patch appears to be broken:

http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/FreeBSD/hackers/2008-04/msg00073.html

Comment: After looking into it for a while longer, looks like you were partially right, Colin. It would appear that a kernel patch is needed to get this kind of functionality into iptables. 

A workaround, however, would be to use the mangle table. You can insert a flag into the DSCP and ECN fields of the IPv4 header, which are often unused. Though doing so may cause problems if your network actually uses something in there.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

One is to use https://code.google.com/p/evilbitchanger/ , a scapy based script that does the Evil Bit setting work for you.

The other is to use raw scapy scripting to craft the packets with Evil bit. As documented, Scapy is capable of setting the [Evil Bit flag quite easily](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html).

```
>>> t=TCP()
>>> t.flags="SA"
>>> t.flags 
18
>>> t
<TCP flags=SA |>
>>> t.flags=23
>>> t
<TCP flags=FSRA |>
>>> i=IP(flags="DF+MF")
>>> i.flags
3
>>> i
<IP flags=MF+DF |>
>>> i.flags=6
>>> i
<IP flags=DF+evil |>
```

Hope this helps.